# Inserting Animation From Style in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

So i have an animation style defined in `Resources/values/styles.xml`

```
  <style name="BottomSheetAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/dock_bottom_enter</item>
  </style>
```

But it gave me compile error:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:windowEnterAnimation' with value '@anim/dock_bottom_enter').

When i changed it into `@+anim/dock_bottom_enter` (notice the plus sign), it gave me another error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1698,3): error MSB6006: "aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819

I have defined the animation in anim folder (`Resources/Anim/dock_bottom_enter.xml`). I also have defined that file as `AndroidResource` in the Solution Explorer.

Strangely, i can access the animation from resoure class (`Resource.Anim.dock_bottom_enter`). Seems like it is actually compiled successfully, but i can't refer animation from style. Is there something i forget to do?

I have tried cleaning, rebuild, changing xml to axml, changing the case (Anim to anim), none of them works. I am using latest Xamarin version (Xamarin Android 6)

Comment: The `@+` syntax is only applicable for identifiers. It tells aapt to dynamically generate a resource identifier for a view element. What locale is your style declared in and what locale is your animation declared in? Could contribute to problem if they are different.

Comment: No locale. I don't use something like `values-ja/styles.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<item name="activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_open_enter</item>
```

Refer  : [https://github.com/android/platformframeworksbase/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L83-L112)

Comment: Does not work. Still get `No resource found that matches given name`